# How to find tangent space to a given manifold?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, manifolds

I have a manifold M, where:

$M = {x^{3}+y^{3}+z^{4}+xyz=4}$

I have to find the tangent space in point p = $(3^{1/3}, 0, -1)$

I know that I have to find ker of DF, where F is a function given by M.
$F(x,y,z) = {x^{3}+y^{3}+z^{4}+xyz-4}$

I don't really see how to find ker, since I don't even know in which base DF is given.

Comment: Ordinarily you would give the tangent space as the solutions of a linear equation, so you don't need to find the basis for $\ker(DF_p)$. You just want the normal vector to the plane and a point through which it passes.

Answer (score 4):

One possible approach: if $M \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is given by $F^{-1}(c)$ for some constant $c$ then $\nabla F$ is orthogonal to $M$ in each point of $M$ (if the gradient vanishes in some point you don't have a manifold). You can then calculate a basis for the tangent space by finding $n-1$ ($2$ in you case) linear independent vectors orthogonal to $\nabla F$. You should have learned how to do this in a linear algebra course.

This is the same as finding the kernel of $DF$ of course, since 
$$DF(v) =\langle \nabla F,v \rangle$$